# Merge two lists and create a new dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I could not find a good way to do this. Suppose I have two lists (the lists have objects with given attributes). I need to create a new dictionary/list with merged atttributes.

```
listA = [
  {
    "alpha": "some value",
    "time": "datetime",
  },
  ...
]

listB = [
  {
    "beta": "some val",
    "gamma": "some val",
    "time": "datetime"
  },
  ...
]
```

The result should be as follows (it should be merged based on "time" attribute)

```
result = {
  "datetime": {
    "alpha": "some value",
    "beta": "some val",
    "gamma": "some val"
  },
  ...
}
```

How do I do this in a python way?

For example,

```
listA = [
  {
    "time": "Jan 1",
    "alpha": "one"
  },
  {
    "time": "Jan 3",
    "alpha": "three"
  }
]

listB = [
  {
    "beta": "one-one",
    "gamma": "one-two",
    "time": "Jan 1"
  },
  {
    "beta": "two-one",
    "gamma": "two-two",
    "time": "Jan 2"
  },
]

result = {
  "Jan 1": {
    "alpha": "one",
    "beta": "one-one",
    "gamma": "one-two",
  },
  "Jan 2": {
    "beta": "two-one",
    "gamma": "two-two",
  },
  "Jan 3": {
    "alpha": "three"
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you *currently* doing it, and what precisely is the problem with that implementation (if the problem is that it doesn't exist, then fix that first...)

Comment: I don't see much evidence that you've tried to solve this yourself.

Comment: I have tried and gotten a solution using for loop. But I want to know if there is a more intuitive way of doing it

Comment: I added another way to my answer that is using list comprehensions. I am not sure that is more intuitive. In my opinion for complex, nested loops, plain "for loops" are more intuitive because the resulting code is more readable. For single loops, however, I find the list comprehensions often cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using a list comprehension

Since you are searching for an alternative not using a for loop here is an implementation using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which results in a two liner. I am not sure though that this is more intuitive than a for loop:

```
output = {}
[output.setdefault(item["time"],{}).update({key: value}) 
 for key, value in item.items()     
 if key != "time" 
 for item in (listA + listB)]
```

To me this is just a more convoluted way of for loops...
Documentation for [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

## Using classic for loops

Use `listA` and `listB` as given in your example:

```
combined = listA + listB

merged = {}
for item in combined:
    time = item["time"]
    # setdefault only acts if the key is not found, initiate a dict then
    merged.setdefault(time, {})
    for key, value in item.items():
        if key != "time":
            merged[time].update({key: value})

print merged
```

Output:

```
{'Jan 2': {'beta': 'two-one', 'gamma': 'two-two'}, 'Jan 3': {'alpha': 'three'}, 'Jan 1': {'alpha': 'one', 'beta': 'one-one', 'gamma': 'one-two'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer, that's perhaps cleaner in that it avoids conditional tests in favour of dict methods and uses only one level of indentation:

```
d={}

for e in listA:
    t = e["time"]
    d.setdefault(t, {}).update(**e)

for e in listB:
    t = e["time"]
    d.setdefault(t, {}).update(**e)

# get rid of "time" keys, if important to do so

for e in d.values():
    del e["time"]
```

`d.setdefault(t, {})` creates `d[t]` as an empty dict if the key `t` is not yet present in `d`, and returns `d[t]`. Then`.update(**e)` updates the returned dict to contain all keys and values in `e` (replacing current values if they exist, which may be a bug or a feature - the example did not have any overlaps or say what should happen if there are overlaps)

Answer (score 0):

This code might be a good start:

```
listA = [
  {
    "time": "Jan 1",
    "alpha": "one"
  },
  {
    "time": "Jan 3",
    "alpha": "three"
  }
]

listB = [
  {
    "beta": "one-one",
    "gamma": "one-two",
    "time": "Jan 1"
  },
  {
    "beta": "two-one",
    "gamma": "two-two",
    "time": "Jan 2"
  },
]
result = {}

# We consider every element of A and B one by one
for elem in listA + listB:
    key = elem["time"]

    # If that is the first time we encounter that key, we create a new empty dict in result
    if not result.get(key, None):
        result[key] = {}

    # We copy the content of the elem in listA or listB into the right dictionnary in result.
    for dictKey in elem.keys():

        # We don't want to copy the time
        if dictKey == "time":
            continue
        result[key][dictKey] = elem[dictKey]
print(result)
```